# Can I get the view holder of item of edittext's text object reference?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Can I get the view holder of item of edittext's text object reference?

My viewholder...

```
override fun bind(list: MutableList<Test>, position: Int) {  
   list.get(position).test.get(0).editable = binding.etTest.text //not reference
   val testEdit = binding.root.findViewById(R.id.et_test) as EditText 
   list.get(position).test.get(0).editable = testEdit.text ////not reference
}
```

when text is changed, list.get(position).test.get(0).editable is not changed..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clarify your question but I assume that you want to use `RecyclerView`. In that scenario, you have to use the `ViewHolder` pattern.

`ViewHolder` is responsible to inflate your View and hold references to your `EditText`(s) or anything that is in your view. Then, in `bind()` method, you can fill that/those `EditText`(s).

Comment: oh, that's working, i mistaked... i don't have to @BindingAdapter with this.. thank you